# How to unset data attribute of object html tag. Empty string shows whole page inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function fn()
{
  document.getElementById('obj').data = "";
 }
```

```html
<div style="background-color:blue">abc
    <object id="obj" data="myImg.svg" type="image/svg" >
  
  
  </object>

</div>

<div style="background-color:red">def

</div>

<br>

<button onclick="fn()">empty the data att</button>
```

I have an object tag. It's data attribute points to an SVG file. I want to dynamically change the data attribute and then to be able to clear it to.

But setting to empty (data="") reconstructs the whole page into the object tag.
How to empty it correctly please?

Comment: Post your code as we can't assume your code!

Comment: Check [removeData](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/)

Comment: I've added some code, but I don't know why it doesn't show the problem. It does happen in my webpage (it is not public yet..).